# Multiples text tags without new line

Tags: html, css, formatting, newline

**Note:** Please don't mark this as duplicate. There are similar questions, but they don't answer my question.

Is there any way to display multiple `<p>` or `<div>` tags without a line break/new line? I've tested around with all the nesting you could think of. Maybe it's impossible?

Here's an example:

```html
<pre>Can multiple tags </pre>
<pre>be merged into a single</pre>
<pre> line?</pre>
<br>
<p>I want the text to all be in one line like this</p>
```

I want the result to be: "Can multiple tags be merged into a single line?"

Thank you.

Comment: There you go!
Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.makeInline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<pre class="makeInline">Can multiple tags</pre>
<pre class="makeInline">be merged into a single</pre>
<pre class="makeInline">line?</pre>
```

[You might have to use `display: inline-block;` for this.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)